# How to pass a Dict to a function with Keyword arguments?

Tags: function, dictionary, julia, mapping

Let's assume I have this `Dict`:

```
d=Dict("arg1"=>10,"arg2"=>20)
```

and a function like this:

```
function foo(;arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5)
  #Do something
end
```

How can I call the function and pass the parameters in the `Dict` d as parameters for the function?
I know I can do this:

```
foo(arg1=d["arg1"],arg2=d["arg2"])
```

But is there any way to automate this? I mean a way to figure out which arguments are defined in the Dict and pass it automatically to the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionaries with `Symbol` keys can be directly `splat`ted into the function call:

```
julia> d = Dict(:arg1 => 10, :arg2 => 12)
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 2 entries:
  :arg1 => 10
  :arg2 => 12

julia> f(; arg1, arg2) = arg1 + arg2
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(; d...)
22
```

Note the semicolon in the function call, which ensure that the elements in `d` are interpreted as keyword arguments instead of positional arguments which just happen to be `Pair`s.

Comment: note that the semi-colon is important to be interpreted as keyword arguments

Comment: Fluent splatting is one of the most amazing things about Julia.  Very important to learn about.